# How to handle epsilon production in CLR(1) parsing?

Tags: compilers

Given the following grammar:

1. S -> A
2. A -> AB
3. A -> ϵ
4. B -> aB
5. B -> b

Check whether it is CLR(1) or not.

I have drawn the canonical itemsets as well as the parse table. But I'm not sure whether it is actually correct or not. I have tried searching for some similar examples that have epsilon productions but could not find any. Could someone please help me out?

[image: My solution to this problem]

Answer (score 2):

$\varepsilon $ is a representation of an empty string. Since it derives literally nothing, it is as good as having scanned the complete production, with the corresponding item set $A\rightarrow \cdot$ and would trigger a $reduce$ action on respective lookahead.